# 7zip build fail with LzFind.c(1613,30): error C2440: void (__stdcall *)(UInt32,CLzRef *,const CLzRef *)”->“LZFIND_SATUR_SUB_CODE_FUNC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, 7zip

I'm trying to build 7-zip(`7z2103-src.7z`) with visual studio 2019.
I opened `7zip_src\Bundles\Fm\FM.dsw` and convert it to vcxproj by vs 2019.
Then set `/Zi` and `/Gy` for project and build it.

vs 2019 gives following errors:

```
1>LzFind.c
1>=== LzFind SSE41
1>C:\Project\7zip-size\C\LzFind.c(1606,28): error C2440: "=": Cannot convert “void (__stdcall *)(UInt32,CLzRef *,const CLzRef *)" to "LZFIND_SATUR_SUB_CODE_FUNC"
1>=== LzFind AVX2
1>C:\Project\7zip-size\C\LzFind.c(1613,30): error C2440: "=": Cannot convert “void (__stdcall *)(UInt32,CLzRef *,const CLzRef *)" to "LZFIND_SATUR_SUB_CODE_FUNC"
```

**But I build successful by nmake (`nmake CPU=AMD64 NEW_COMPILER=1 MY_STATIC_LINK=1`), is there more settings required for this project?**

piece of code occur error in 7-zip source:

```
MY_NO_INLINE
static
#ifdef ATTRIB_SSE41
ATTRIB_SSE41
#endif
void LzFind_SaturSub_128(UInt32 subValue, CLzRef *items, const CLzRef *lim)
{
  v128 sub2 =
    #ifdef MY_CPU_ARM_OR_ARM64
      vdupq_n_u32(subValue);
    #else
      _mm_set_epi32((Int32)subValue, (Int32)subValue, (Int32)subValue, (Int32)subValue);
    #endif
  do
  {
    SASUB_128(0)
    SASUB_128(1)
    SASUB_128(2)
    SASUB_128(3)
    items += 4 * 4;
  }
  while (items != lim);
}

......


void LzFindPrepare()
{
  #ifndef FORCE_SATUR_SUB_128
  #ifdef USE_SATUR_SUB_128
  LZFIND_SATUR_SUB_CODE_FUNC f = NULL;
  #ifdef MY_CPU_ARM_OR_ARM64
  {
    if (CPU_IsSupported_NEON())
    {
      #pragma message ("=== LzFind NEON")
      _PRF(printf("\n=== LzFind NEON\n"));
      f = LzFind_SaturSub_128;
    }
    // f = 0; // for debug
  }
  #else // MY_CPU_ARM_OR_ARM64
  if (CPU_IsSupported_SSE41())
  {
    #pragma message ("=== LzFind SSE41")
    _PRF(printf("\n=== LzFind SSE41\n"));
    f = LzFind_SaturSub_128; // <- Error occurred here

    #ifdef USE_AVX2
    if (CPU_IsSupported_AVX2())
    {
      #pragma message ("=== LzFind AVX2")
      _PRF(printf("\n=== LzFind AVX2\n"));
      f = LzFind_SaturSub_256; // <- Error occurred here
    }
    #endif
  }
  #endif // MY_CPU_ARM_OR_ARM64
  g_LzFind_SaturSub = f;
  #endif // USE_SATUR_SUB_128
  #endif // FORCE_SATUR_SUB_128
}
```

Declarations of LZFIND_SATUR_SUB_CODE_FUNC and LzFind_SaturSub_256:

```
#ifndef FORCE_SATUR_SUB_128
typedef void (MY_FAST_CALL *LZFIND_SATUR_SUB_CODE_FUNC)(
    UInt32 subValue, CLzRef *items, const CLzRef *lim);
static LZFIND_SATUR_SUB_CODE_FUNC g_LzFind_SaturSub;
#endif // FORCE_SATUR_SUB_128

#ifdef ATTRIB_AVX2
ATTRIB_AVX2
#endif

void LzFind_SaturSub_256(UInt32 subValue, CLzRef *items, const CLzRef *lim)
{
  __m256i sub2 = _mm256_set_epi32(
      (Int32)subValue, (Int32)subValue, (Int32)subValue, (Int32)subValue,
      (Int32)subValue, (Int32)subValue, (Int32)subValue, (Int32)subValue);
  do
  {
    SASUB_256(0)
    SASUB_256(1)
    items += 2 * 8;
  }
  while (items != lim);
}
#endif // USE_AVX2
```

Update:
Errors dissappear and build fm.exe successful after switch project to x64 build.

Comment: What are the declarations of `LZFIND_SATUR_SUB_CODE_FUNC` and `LzFind_SaturSub_256`? [Edit] these details into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just add C\CpuArch.c to your project

Comment: This also helps for similar problems (in my case there were just some externals missing).